# How to run method completed when app closing?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How to run onEndSession completed ?

```
private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
{
    onEndSession ();
}

async public static void onEndSession()
{
    try
    {
        if (Utilities.isInternet())
        {
            string data = "...";
            string parmater = "...;
            string response = await Utilities.sendData(parmater, data);
            JObject _object = JObject.Parse(response);
            string sucess = (string)_object["success"];
            if (sucess == "1")
                delObject();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string temp = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

When app closing onEndSession() is not run complete,when

```
string response = await Utilities.sendData(parmater, data)
```

run complete and then it is not continues run

```
JObject _object = JObject.Parse(response);
.......
```

but when app is running, `onEndSession()` method will be run complete

How do solution?

Comment: You don't have error in ouput windows on await Utilities.sendData(parmater, data) ?

Comment: Yes,don't have error,but if i put onEndSession() method in application launching,this method will be run completed.

Answer (score 2):

Since the app mustn't exit before your call is done, use a synchronous call instead of an asynchronous one:

```
string response = Utilities.sendData(parmater, data).Result;
```

Please note that you've got only a few seconds before the OS kills your app, which means your network call will likely fail if the phone has low connectivity. You may want to find some way to do that processing while the application is still alive rather than waiting for the `Closing` event.